# Lost huge shade tree now AC/temp is suffering - are sun shades an option?

Tags: roof, landscaping, tree

Lost a huge shady camphor that filtered sunlight for about 75% of the house (1 story, ranch style, 1200sqft). Obviously another tree won't be viable for several decades but is there a way to use sunsails/shades to gain a similar effect? Not sure what my neighbors would think of it, but not too concerned there. I assume I would have to put up poles to hold the shades and have some way of lowering them/removing them during hurricanes. Is there an obvious reason people don't do this more that I'm missing?

Comment: Another name for sun shades is wind sails.  The anchoring is very important even with light wind.  It will depend on how your house is insulated and how many windows.  Possible just window films or window awnings will work also.  Enough/large amount of sun shade for the house might be close to amount of money for decent size tree(totally unknown).

Comment: Remember - wind on a sail is what moved ships around the world for centuries before steam power. Wind will look at a 4x4 and laugh at the toothpick before snapping it.

Comment: Time to improve the attic insulation. Could put small awnings on some windows.

Answer (score 6):

**Pergola**

I built something similar to this:

[image]

Very easy to make, many options for the structure. Vine grows on it, in the summer leaves block the sun and make shade on the windows ; in the winter the leaves fall off and it lets the sun in.

Only drawback is I have to trim the vegetation once a year.

This is also quite wind proof, due to being full of holes.

Here's another one:

[image]

Basically you need a structure (metal, wood, your choice) either suspended from the wall or resting on feet/columns. Then pull some wire through it, for example every 20cm, to act as support for the plants. You can see the wires in the pic. Choice of plants depends on climate, but the faster they grow, the more trimming you'll have to do.

Wisteria will give flowers in the spring, then shade as leaves grow at the beginning of summer. They will also colonize your roof if you let them.

[image]

Comment: Are these steel rods embedded in a brick or stone wall? How deep into the wall do they go?  How thick is the wall? Are the rods braced above by cables?

Comment: @JimStewart as far as the random internet photo is concerned, I have no idea. I built mine out of square steel tubes, suspended to the wall with a steel cable. Can't post a photo because I've temporarily taken it down to install exterior insulation.